# Rewrite DIR to subdomain URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need to rewrite the URL from `https://example.com/dir/files` to `https://dir.example.com/files`. When the user finishes registration on my website, the system creates a new directory for that user. That directory name depends on what the user enters as a username, so that means if the user enters `moderator` as username, the directory will get the name `moderator` so his URL need's to be `https://moderator.example.com/files`. I try with this code, but not working for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^dir/install$ https://dir.example.com/install? [R=301,L]
```

My complete `.htacess` file:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^dir/install$ https://dir.example.com/install? [R=301,L]

disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes
```

I don't have experience with `.htaccess` so can someone explain to me how this works and where I make mistakes. Thanks all.

Comment: In what way does this "not work" exactly? Are you getting an error? Incorrect redirect? Nothing? What other directives do you have in the `.htaccess` and where exactly have you put this rule? As written, this rule would redirect `/dir/install` (any domain) to `https://dir.example.com/install`.

Comment: When I try to open ```https://dir.example.com/install```I get a 500 error but ```install.php``` file is empty. I enter that code in ```.htaccess``` file. @MrWhite

Comment: And please read carefully what I write. The directory I need to rename as the subdomain is dynamic. So any user who registered will get a directory with a different name. @MrWhite

Comment: Any reason why you are matching an empty query string? Although you are also _removing_ the query string in the same rule - which is certainly unnecessary (if there is no query string to begin with).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the directives as posted.

- MultiViews needs to be disabled. This is conflicting with the first rule that appends the `.php` extension via an internal rewrite.
- The directives are in the wrong order. The redirect to the subdomain needs to be before the rule that appends the `.php` extension.
- The rule that appends `.php` isn't strictly correct, since `.php` is appended to "any" URL that does not exist, even though the target `.php` file might also not exist.

I've made a few additional assumptions in order to determine the URL that should be redirected to the subdomain:

- The URL consists of exactly two path segments, ie. `/<subdomain>/<file>` (no trailing slash).
- The `<file>` (and `<subdomain>`) cannot contain dots.
- `/<subdomain>/<file>` cannot map to a physical directory.

Try the following instead:

```
# Disable directory browsing and MultiViews
Options All -Indexes -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example\.com) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ https://$1.%1/$2 [R=302,L]

# Internal rewrite to append ".php" extension
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

The `%1` backreference in the first rule contains the domain name captured from the preceding *condition*. Unlike the `$n` backreferences that are captured from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

> On page when i open it as `https://dir.example.com/install` i get `admin.example.com`’s DNS address could not be found. Diagnosing the problem.

You need to make sure the DNS is correctly configured (presumably with a "wildcard" subdomain) and the server is configured to receive such requests. This is not covered in the above rules.

Comment: I have configured ```wildcard``` correctly. The problem in your code is that content from ```https://example.com/index```is now on ```https://folder.example.com``` and that is not what I write or what I need. I have written with an explanation of what I need. I need this URL ```https://example.com/folder/{ALL FILES AND FOLDER}``` to be rewritten in ```https://folder.example.com/{ALL FILES AND FOLDER}```. Note: users after registration will be redirected to ```https://example.com/folder/{FILES AND FOLDERS}``` and username depends on what they write in the username field.

Comment: @Jerry "The problem in your code is that content from `https://example.com/index` is now on `https://folder.example.com`" - The code I posted does not do that. (Make sure you have cleared your browser cache.) As I stated, the code assumes a URL-path format of `/<subdomain>/<file>` where `<subdomain>` is the first path segment that forms the subdomain after the redirect. The regex in the first rule `^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$` specifically matches two path segments. It does not match a request for `https://example.com/index`.

Comment: @Jerry Presumably the domain apex and subdomains all point to the same document root? What you've not stated in your question (so I have not covered in my answer) is how requests for the subdomain are routed to the correct file? Is the file in the document root, or in the same subdirectory as initially requested?

Comment: I didn't ask to help me about what I didn't ask for help. My question is clear and I clearly describe my problem. Any suggestions about my problem and tips to resolve it? I try over  48 hours to resolve this issue, but not working. I have cleared my cache and i use 3 different browsers and still got the same problem. Files from ```user directory``` is not displayed under ```https://userdir.site.com```.